# Get CVS history for a particular user

Tags: cvs, tortoisecvs

How do I get the history of commits that have been made to the repository for a particular user?

I am able to access CVS either through the command line or TortioseCVS, so a solution using either method is sufficient.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
cvs history -u username
```

gives a history of changes the user has made

Answer (score 14):

As a coder, I am mostly interested in commit changes, (as opposed to tagging, branching, etc), so I usually include the `-c` commit option as well:

```
cvs history -c -u username
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try this one:

```
cvs history -x AMR -D "your-desired-date"
```

Example

```
cvs history -x AMR -D "2012-04-12"
```

Comment: I have give an example, Have you try it ? ;)

Comment: I appreciate that you're being playful, but I had to `cvs --help history` to figure this out.

Flag "-x" is extract by record type. Flag "-D" <date> is since date (Many formats).

Comment: @aaaidan, I'm sorry about that. Thanks for completing the commands description.