# CVS list by user checkin

Tags: cvs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get CVS history for a particular user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57183/get-cvs-history-for-a-particular-user)

Is it possible to list all checkins/commits done by a specific user?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57183/get-cvs-history-for-a-particular-user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

history -c -uUSERNAME -D2009-03-25

Lists all checking done by  since 2009-03-25

Answer (score 2):

```
cvs history -c -u «user»
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
cvs log -w<loginname> <filename>
```